# Configuración del Heartbeat del consumidor en CANopen

Tags: mensajes

Tengo la siguiente situación. Tengo un maestro (consumidor) y un esclavo (productor), el esclavo tiene que estar entre los nodos 1-127, en este caso el esclavo está en el nodo 125.

Estoy tratando de sincronizar ambos, para eso, después de algunas investigaciones, encontré la función de latido del corazón.
Soy bastante nuevo con `CANopen`, así que intenté cambiar los valores en el archivo `master.dcf`.
Si conoces `CANopen` sabrás que existen varios parámetros que son iguales para todos, por lo que puedes configurarlos de la forma que necesites.
En este caso, he modificado el parámetro `1017h` (tiempo de latido del corazón del productor) cambiando el `DefaultValue` a `1000 ms` para que cada segundo reciba un latido del corazón del productor (esclavo).
Aquí puedes ver el `master.dcf` donde hice el cambio:

```
[1017]
ParameterName=Producer heartbeat time
DataType=0x0006
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=1000
```

Mi problema es hacer lo mismo con el maestro (consumidor).
Para esto, en el `master.dcf` se supone que el parámetro `1016h` (tiempo de latido del consumidor) funciona de la misma manera que el `1017h` pero no sé qué cambiar aquí para obtener un latido del maestro cada segundo.
Aquí está el `1016h` en el `master.dcf`

```
[1016]
ParameterName=Consumer heartbeat time
ObjectType=0x08
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
CompactSubObj=127

[1016Value]
NrOfEntries=0
```

Como mencioné, he intentado modificar el valor de `NrOfEntries`, pero no creo que esto sea algo relevante para mi caso, así que lo dejé como estaba (`NrOfEntries = 0`).

También he probado con otros dos parámetros: `1006h` y `1007h`.

```
[1006]
ParameterName=Communication cycle period
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=0

[1007]
ParameterName=Synchronous window length
DataType=0x0007
AccessType=rw
DefaultValue=0
```

Ambos tienen un valor inicial de **0**, y he intentado cambiarlos a **1**, pero todavía no puedo ver el oído del esclavo.

Para ver que pasa en `CAN` estoy usando `candump can0` en una terminal y puedo ver cada mensaje de la comunicacion, en la siguiente imagen pueden ver una parte de la comunicacion:

[image: Imagen candump]

Como puedes ver en la imagen, la línea `can0 701 [1] 05` es la línea del latido del productor que aparece cada segundo, según lo configurado. Las otras líneas son para la inicialización de `CAN` (mensajes `NMT`) y la apertura y cierre de válvulas.

Por si a alguien le parece importante. Como maestro estoy usando una `NVIDIA Xavier` y como esclavo tengo un modulo `CR2041` de `ifm`, al que le he conectado unas válvulas para poder controlarlas. La comunicación ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicación que controla las válvulas.

Si necesitas más información para ayudarme pídela sin problemas.